# Anonymous class objects: which variables do they see?

Tags: java, android

A common situation when writing an Android app: scheduling a `Runnable` to make some drawing work on a `View`:

```
class MyView extends View {
...
  private void start() {

        final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors
                .newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        mMoverFuture = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (isOutOfView()) {
                    mMoverFuture.cancel(false);
                }

                postInvalidate(); // Can I do this?
            }
        }, 0, REFRESH_RATE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
...
}
```

Particularly, I am not sure if I can call `MyView`s method `postInvalidate()` from the thread's `run()`. Which rules should one follow when judging which variables and methods are available to an anonymous class object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Java rules an instance of InnerClass has direct access to the methods and fields of its enclosing instance. If you have doubts you can check it [in Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Method postInvalidate, in its turn, is designed especially to be invoked outside of UI thread so it also doesn't violate Android View's restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

There are no rules. You can call any variables from parent class. In your case all you need to remember it is **[thread safety](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076747/core-java/design-for-thread-safety.html)**. Take care about this, if it is important for you.